# Node / SystemJS / Angular 2 "Error: evalmachine.<anonymous>:1"

Tags: node.js, angular, systemjs

I'm currently in an Angular 2 project and everything was working well.

After I merged the master branch of the concerned project into my feature branch, this error `Error: evalmachine.<anonymous>:1` occurred. The worst: still after resetting my branch to an earlier time (when the branch was actually working) this error won't disappear.

I'm not even sure where this error comes from. The only thing I know is that this error appears nearly immediately when loading the angular 2 app.

I'm REALLY desperate, since my branch was a lot of work and it seems not to be resettable. Does anybody have an idea? Any solution is badly needed!

Thanks folks!

Comment: Have you tried removing the `node_modules` directory, and executed another `npm install` ?

Comment: I did, unfortunately, without success :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, stupid me!

This error came up, because obviously some dependencies of the project have been damaged / removed / whatever. The project has a batch file where all those dependencies will be reinstalled. After executing it, everything works as expected again. Hopefully this may help others that experience the same problem.

So basicly @PierreDuc was right, but due to the project there was simply more to do than "only" reinstall node_modules..

Thanks for you having tried to help anyway, was a good starting point!
Cheers

Comment: Glad to have given a nudge :)